# Why don't my modules install in my current python environment?

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, virtual-environment

I have a recurrent problem I have yet been unable to find an answer to.
Whenever I install a package in PyCharm through the terminal, whenever I try importing the module the package appears to not be installed. Or, like just now, the package may already be installed but when importing the module I get the error *"No module named x"*:

```
C:\Users\TimStack\PycharmProjects\API>pip install requests
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\TimStack\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (2.23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\TimStack\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2019.11.28)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\TimStack\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2.9)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\TimStack\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from requests) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\TimStack\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from requests) (1.25.8)
```

Looking at these directories, it seems to refer to an old Python 3.7 installation. However, my environment uses **3.8**.

What's the issue at hand here, and how do I go about solving it?

Comment: check the interpreter in PyCharm which might be different than the one with the modules installed

Comment: @sK500 the current interpreter is 3.8. I intend to install in 3.8, but that is not happening judging from those directories

Comment: Go to `preferences > project > python interpreter` there should be a list of available libraries ... is numpy listed? if not click on the `+` sign down there and install numpy or whatever package you want.

Comment: @sK500 that's how I've been doing it but I prefer to do it through the terminal as it's quicker

Comment: I usually do it through the terminal on my macbook too I'm just saying if the package does not show up in the list then you're using a different interpreter than your system's

Comment: if you're using `pip install` change it to `pip3 install`

Comment: @sK500 it's not about just p3,  OP has multiple versions of python3 on his system. He wants to force pip to install against a particular python version.

Comment: @Mahori that's why i indicated above to check the list of available libraries in the project interpreter because if the one he needs shows up, this would be the correct interpreter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to uninstall the old 3.7 version as you have 2 conflicting Python versions.

**OR**

Specify your Python version when installing packages:

```
pip3.8 install [package name]
```

(3.8 for Python 3.8)

Comment: `pip-3.8 install requests` gives the error `'pip-3.8' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Sorry, remove the `-` and make it `pip3.8`

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Are there any more "permanent" solutions? Something that wouldn't force me to specify the python version and without me having to uninstall 3.7?

Comment: @TimStack no sorry, apart from uninstalling there is no other option as far as I know

Answer (score 1):

`pip install` takes `--python-version <python_version>` as argument. 
You can pass 3.8 as argument and it will pick up the right one for you.

**from the docs -**

The Python interpreter version to use for wheel and "Requires-
                              Python" compatibility checks. Defaults to a version derived from
                              the running interpreter. The version can be specified using up
                              to three dot-separated integers (e.g. "3" for 3.0.0, "3.7" for
                              3.7.0, or "3.7.3"). A major-minor version can also be given as a
                              string without dots (e.g. "37" for 3.7.0).

Comment: `pip install requests --python-version 3.8` returns the error `ERROR: When restricting platform and interpreter constraints using --python-version, --platform, --abi, or --implementation, either --no-deps must be set, or --only-binary=:all: must be set and --no-binary must not be set (or must be set to :none:).`